# if statement containing multiple lookups

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vlookup

I need to create a formula that has three lookup criteria.  I have one source document, called "Sales Force".  I want to know if the value in A1 is in column AA of Sales force tab, if not, then look for the value in A3 in the sales force tab, if still nothing, then look for the value in A5 in the sales force tab, otherwise, enter zero.

Answer (score 2):

What do you want to return if the value is found?

Since you only look in one column, Vlookup is not required.

```
=IF(COUNTIF('Sales Force'!AA:AA,A1)>0,"found",IF(COUNTIF('Sales Force'!AA:AA,A3)>0,"found",IF(COUNTIF('Sales Force'!AA:AA,A5)>0,"found",0)))
```

or

```
=COUNTIF('Sales Force'!AA:AA,A1)+COUNTIF('Sales Force'!AA:AA,A3)+COUNTIF('Sales Force'!AA:AA,A5)
```

Comment: I think your first formula comes closer to what Teresa is asking for, although it's hard to know without seeing the data or having a clearer statement of what is to be returned. (I'm thinking of a situation where there is some combination in AA of the values in A1, A3, and A5, in which case the second formula would count them all.)